# angular: HttpInterceptor not catching every request

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors

I wrote an HttpInterceptor (Angular 4.3.6) to catch all requests and manipulate some header fields. My problem is that it is not catching every request. What could be the problem?

Here my interceptor:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {


    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        console.log('AuthInterceptor at work: ', req.url );

        const contentTypeReq = req.clone({
            headers: req.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        });

        const token  = localStorage.getItem('token');
        if (token) {
            const authReq = contentTypeReq.clone({
                headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token)
            });
            return next.handle(authReq);
        }

        //debug - lazy loading
        //contentTypeReq.headers.keys()

        return next.handle(contentTypeReq);
    }
}


export const AuthInterceptorProvider = {
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass: AuthInterceptor,
    multi: true,
};
```

And here a request that is not caught:

```
...
login(username: string, password: string): Observable<boolean> {

        return this.http.post(environment.baseUrl + '/api/authenticate', JSON.stringify({ username: username, password: password }))
            .map((response: Response) => {
...
```

Perhaps I have some interference with my second interceptor that should redirect on 401 errors:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/empty';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/finally';
import {
    HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpErrorResponse, HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor,
HttpRequest
} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(private router: Router) {}

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        console.log('Error interceptor at work: ', req.url);

        return next.handle(req)
            .do(event => {
                console.log('error interceptor in success', event);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log('error interceptor in error', err);
                if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse && err.status === 401) {

                    if (err.url !== '/login') {
                        console.log('redirecting to login...');
                        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
                    }
                }
                return Observable.throw(err);
                // or return Observable.empty();
            })
            .finally(() => {
                console.log('error finally');
            });
    }
}


export const ErrorInterceptorProvider = {
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass: ErrorInterceptor,
    multi: true,
};
```

And here is how I integrate them in my app.module:

```
  providers: [
    AuthGuard,
    AuthenticationService,
    UserService,
    MockBackend,
    BaseRequestOptions,
    GoogleAnalyticsEventsService,
    ErrorInterceptorProvider,
    AuthInterceptorProvider
  ]
```

Comment: There can be any problem. Can you reproduce it? Are you using only one interceptor?

Comment: Could you please set up your project [here](https://stackblitz.com/)?

Comment: Yes I can reproduce it. What do you need to know? I'm using a second interceptor to catch errors. Will add this in my edit above

Comment: did you fix your problem? i have the same problem !

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is actually with your import of `HttpClientModule`.

See my full answer here: [HTTP_INTERCEPTORS only in AppModule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53344221/http-interceptors-only-in-appmodule/57007882#57007882)

Answer (score -2):

I have found that my issue was that interceptor has to be provided in every module in Angular application, where you want to intercept requests, not just container module.

Comment: I don't think this is the right approach. Suggesting this will also create multiple of the same providers for the application. 
If for some reason there is state inside of that service, that will be another hurdle to overcome.

Comment: It is working, if you have better solution you are welcomed to provide answer.