# HTTP_INTERCEPTORS only in AppModule

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors

I am trying to implement lazy loading in my Angular 6 app, all of my http calls are made in the `FeatureModule` (lazy loaded), but still I have to add `HttpClientModule` in my `AppModule` and not in `FeatureModule`. Didn't really understand why.
Also, when I added interceptors in my `FeatureModule`, they didn't intercept any request. I have to add it in the `AppModule` only (I guess, it is because `HttpClientModule` is in `AppModule`).

I want to understand why this is the case?? Why can't we have `HttpClientModule` and `HTTP_INTERCEPTORS` only in the `FeatureModule` and not in `AppModule` where I am not making any `http` calls?

Comment: Its not required to `HttpClientModule` in `AppModule` however you need to immediate `Module` which uses `Http`. Better to put into `SharedModule`  instead.

Comment: @SunilSinghit gives error if I don't use HttpClientModule in AppModule

Comment: It means you did not add `HttpClientModule` in all `Modules` which is using `Http`.

Comment: @SunilSingh I did not add HttpClientModule to the AppModule as it was not making any Http requests and had added it only to the FeatureModule as it was the only module making Http requests. However, that was not working and I had to add HttpClientModule to the AppModule in order to get rid of the error. I am not sure where I went wrong.

Comment: Please create stackblitz demo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer this question.

Only add `HttpClientModule` at once place at the root level. No other modules regardless of how they are imported `lazy` or `eager` even if it is from a library. Ensure that it is not importing `HttpClientModule`

You can however use HTTP_INTERCEPTORS providers across modules without an issue.

When you import `HttpClientModule` across modules and then re import that into another module it effectively resets the providers for HTTP_INTERCEPTORS for that module.
This is an intended behaviour. If you need more information about the discussion you can check: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20575

Answer (score 0):

The last answer it's great, best practices say that you only need one HtppclientModule and it's better if you put this into core.module.ts and import core.module.ts into app.module.ts.

core.module.ts

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAKa9.png)

app.module.ts

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATdjK.png)

Comment: Please do not post code blocks as images. https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30607889)